# Who did Ethan kill?

Tags: lost

In the episode [*Outlaws* (S01E16)](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Outlaws_transcript), Charlie and Sayid discuss Ethan Rom, saying

> SAYID: You killed a man.
>
> CHARLIE: A man who killed one of us, who kidnapped Claire, who strung me up and left me for dead. He deserved to die. I'd do it again in a minute. Pardon me, if I'm fresh out of bad feeling.

Ethan did kidnap Claire, left Charlie for dead, and possibly attacked Jack, but I don't recall him killing anyone at this point, and [his wikia page](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Ethan_Rom) doesn't mention anything.

**Who does Charlie think Ethan killed?**

Comment: In the following episode, Locke also mentions someone having been murdered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Jackson, one of the very minor, forgettable characters:

From http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Scott_Jackson:

> On day 28 Scott's corpse was found on the beach, with several broken
>   bones, battered and bloody. He was allegedly murdered by Ethan when
>   the group did not give Claire back, as he said he would kill the rest
>   of the group one by one. Scott was the first person buried in the
>   survivors' graveyard, and Hurley gave his eulogy at his funeral and
>   apologized for mistaking him for Steve so often.

It was never outright confirmed that Ethan murdered him, but everybody assumed so.

Comment: Ah, the redshirt. Thanks.